# Vuex persistedState does not work after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuex

I installed persisted state with npm install --save vuex-persistedstate.

Then I setup my Vuex store.js file like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    title: ''
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  getters: {},
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

..And in another component I'm passing value to store.title:

```
this.$store.state.title = this.input
```

And it works.

But after I refresh the page (F5), `this.input` is not anymore stored in `this.$store.state.title`, and it breaks my site functionality.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I got it working really Vanilla style:

First:

```
this.$store.state.title = this.input
localStorage.setItem('title', this.$store.state.title)
```

Then:

```
mounted () {
    this.$store.state.title = localStorage.getItem('title')
  }
```

Would still like to know, why the Vuex plugin is not working :(

Comment: Can you verify that the data are being updated correctly in your localStorage in the browser?

Comment: There is only key `loglevel:webpack-dev-server` and value: `WARN`

Answer (score 1):

can you try applying below code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    title: ''
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  getters: {},
  plugins: [createPersistedState({
     key: 'keyname',
     storage: window.localStorage         
  })]
})
```

inside the "createPersistedState" you can set the path as well 'paths: ['accessRights']' as a another property. if you not provide a paths then the whole sate will be persistence

Answer (score 0):

I am using #vuex store modules and this worked for me for my #vue #vuex #laravel application to persist store state using #vuex-persistedstate. More if you are not using HTTPS then keep secure false.

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';
   import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
   Vue.use(Vuex);
   export default new Vuex.Store({
     strict:true,
   modules:{
    party,
    contract
    },
   plugins: [createPersistedState(
    {
        paths:['party.selectedParty','contract.contracts', 
   'contract.partyId', 
   'contract.partyContracts',
        'contract.selectedContract',

         ],
        storage: {
            getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
            setItem: (key, value) => Cookies.set(key, value, { expires: 3, 
         secure: false }),
            removeItem: key => Cookies.remove(key)
          },

    }
       )],
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reason, sometimes it's not updating state in cookies. Simpliest solution is just changing storage to localstorage by doing following:

```
      createPersistedState({
                key: 'somekey',
                storage: window.localStorage,
        // getState: (key) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
        // setState: (key, state) => Cookies.set(key, state, { expires: 3, secure: true })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this extension had the same problem, however, I realized that the problem is not stemming from my misusage of Vuex. I changed state values by `this.$storage.state.VARIABLENAME`. It was wrong. When I re-read Vuex documentation I realized that I should have to access the state values over *mutations*. When I did this the extension worked properly.

You should modify state values by this way:

```
context.commit("SET_VARIABLENAME","value")
```

While in your mutations in Vuex store the situation should be like below:

```
mutations: {
   
    SET_VARIABLENAME(state,status){
      state.MYVARIABLE= status
    },
```

and in the state block of Vuex:

```
state: {
    MYVARIABLE: null,
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's only when a `commit` call is done:

**index.js`:**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    count() {
      return store.state.count;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    assign() {
      store.state.count = 4;
    },
    increment() {
      store.commit("increment");
    },
    decrement() {
      store.commit("decrement");
    }
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ count }}</p>
  <p>
    <button @click="increment">+</button>
    <button @click="decrement">-</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button @click="assign">Assign 4</button>
  </p>
  <small>
    Check out your localStorage to see the updates.
  </small>
</div>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vuex-persistedstate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Basic example of the vuex-persistedstate plugin",
  "keywords": ["vue", "vuex", "vuex-persistedstate"],
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "2.5.22",
    "vuex": "3.1.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "2.5.4"
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuex-persistedstate-fhb4o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark